# Como configurar un pool de conexiones Apache Tomcat->PostgreSQL->Persistence Java

Tags: java, jpa, tomcat

Tengo un proyecto de Java Web con Java8 utilizando postgresql 9.3 en un Servidor Apache Tomcat7. Estoy utilizando Persistence para la conexion con la base de datos pero no logro configurar el Pool de conexiones de Apache Tomcat para gestionar el trafico de la App con la Base de Datos.

Hasta ahora he buscado en diferentes foros y lo que he encontrado es en el fichero context.xhtml de Apache tomcat adicionar estas lineas:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ead" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000" username="postgres" password="postgres" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/SIGENU_EaD"/>
```

En el fichero web.xml del proyecto web adicionar estas lineas:

```
<resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/ead</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>org.postgresql.Driver</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Mi pregunta es como adicionar esta configuracion al fichero persistence.xml para que al utilizar los JpaControllers generados por persistence utilicen el pool de apache tomcat en vez de una conexion directa.

El fichero persistence.xml actual se ve asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="dist_educ_finalPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>entity.EstadoCivil</class>
        <class>entity.ProcedenciaEscolar</class>
        <class>entity.Disciplina</class>
        <class>entity.Planestudio</class>
        <class>entity.FuenteIngreso</class>
        <class>entity.TipoAsignatura</class>
        <class>entity.Especialidad</class>
        <class>entity.MatriculaEstudianteAsignatura</class>
        <class>entity.Organismo</class>
        <class>entity.Asignatura</class>
        <class>entity.Huerfano</class>
        <class>entity.Tutor</class>
        <class>entity.ColorPiel</class>
        <class>entity.GradoMilitar</class>
        <class>entity.EspecialidadMilitar</class>
        <class>entity.Authorities</class>
        <class>entity.Ocupacion</class>
        <class>entity.Carreranacional</class>
        <class>entity.Minusvalia</class>
        <class>entity.Estudiante</class>
        <class>entity.Sexo</class>
        <class>entity.NivelEscolar</class>
        <class>entity.Users</class>
        <class>entity.Universidad</class>
        <class>entity.OrganizacionPolitica</class>
        <class>entity.OrganizacionPopular</class>
        <class>entity.Municipio</class>
        <class>entity.TipoEvaluacion</class>
        <class>entity.Examen</class>
        <class>entity.Matricula</class>
        <class>entity.MatriculaEstudianteAsignaturaExamen</class>
        <class>entity.Pais</class>
        <class>entity.Centrotrabajo</class>
        <class>entity.EstadoEstudiante</class>
        <class>entity.Curso</class>
        <class>entity.Provincia</class>
        <class>entity.Ong</class>
        <class>entity.Sindicato</class>
        <class>entity.Area</class>
        <class>entity.Carrera</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SIGENU_EaD"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a [xerx593](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592355/xerx593) de stackoverflow en inglés por responder esta misma pregunta publicada ahí. Funcionó a la perfección. La respuesta al problema es la siguiente:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="dist_educ_finalPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">   
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/ead</non-jta-data-source>
    ...
  </persistence-unit>
<persistence>
```

Comment: Con esas lineas se podría solucionar este problema que tengo?               `Hubo un error: org.jpox.exceptions.TransactionNotActiveException: La transacción no es activo. Usted tiene que poner este en una transacción o usar 
su PersistenceManagerFactory con 'NonTransactionalRead' como 'true'`

Comment: JohnG, nunca habia escuchado hablar de ese problema, tienes q ver, qué estas utilizando para crear una conexión con la base de datos. Yo utilizo EntityManagerFactory y JPAControllers para el acceso a datos.